# Update column with concatenated date (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update a column with the concatenated and converted results of two other columns in order to create a column with a date field. The SELECT statement returns the values I want to Update with, but I'm missing something (probably simple) on the update. It won't execute because

> "the subquery returns more than one value".

However, I don't want to update with the same value for each row, but rather the concatenated result for each row.

What am I missing?

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myDate = 
(
SELECT 
CONVERT (Date,(CONVERT (NVarchar, CreatedYear) + '-' + CONVERT (NVarchar, CreatedMonth) + '-' + '01') ,0)

FROM myTable
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have an extra SELECT that is not required.  Please try:

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET myDate =  
CONVERT (Date,(CONVERT (NVarchar, CreatedYear) + '-' + CONVERT (NVarchar, CreatedMonth) + '-' + '01') ,0) 

FROM myTable
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks Steve and Eric.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more readable in my opinion:

```
UPDATE dbo.tblControlMaster SET AuditAddDate = CAST(CreatedYear AS NVARCHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(CreatedMonth AS NVARCHAR(2)) + '-' + '01'
```